# how to change labels for example en to english using ngx-translate

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I'm using ngx-translate in project.
I have created  files `en.json` and `it.json` inside `assets/i18n`
In component language I write this code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.translate.addLangs([
      'it',
      'en'
  ]);
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('it');
    const browserLang = this.translate.getBrowserLang();
    this.translate.use(browserLang.match(/it/) ? browserLang : 'it');
  }
```

in html:

```
<div class="dropdown-language">
    <label for="language">{{'LABEL.LINGUA' | translate }} &nbsp;</label>
        <select #langSelect (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)" class="lang-style" id="language"> 
          <option *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" [value]="lang" [selected]="lang === translate.currentLang">{{ lang }}</option>
        </select>   
</div>
```

This code works very well, in page showed a dropdown with option `it` and `en`

I want to change my code, because in page I must show option `Italian` and `English`, not `it` and `en`.

I can also do it by changing the names from `it` to `Italian` and `en` to `English`, but I think there could be a better solution than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const LANGUAGES: Array<{ name: string; code: string }> = [
    { name: 'English', code: 'EN' },
    { name: 'Português (BR)', code: 'PT_BR' },
    { name: 'Japanese', code: 'JA' },
    { name: 'Italiano', code: 'IT' },
    { name: 'Français', code: 'FR' },
    { name: 'Español', code: 'ES' },
    { name: 'German', code: 'DE' }
];
```

And in HTML you can iterate over the language list